# React native release build for different architecture creates 4 apks

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to reduce the apk size so i changed
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
this created 4 apk's as below

1. app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
2. app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
3. app-x86_64-release.apk
4. app-x86-release.apk

I thought it would create 2 apks , one for x86 and other for arm64.
Do i have to upload all 4 apk's to google play store?
Also which apk support which types of devices ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just upload all those files in Google Play console.

Answer (score 0):

> just add below code in android/app/build.gradle

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

android{
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
}
```